# Optimization of my Custom RAND() query

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I use the following query to get a random row in MySql. And, I think it to be pretty faster than the `ORDER BY RAND()` as it just returns a row after a random count of rows, and doesn't require any ordering of rows.

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE_NAME

!-- GENERATE A RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN 0 and COUNT(ID)-1 --!

SELECT x FROM TABLE_NAME LIMIT RANDOM_NUMBER,1
```

But, I need to know if in any way I could optimize it more and is there a faster method.

I would also be grateful to know if I can combine the 2 queries as `LIMIT` doesn't support such sub-queries **(As I know)**.

**EDIT-** The way my query works is not by randomly generating any ID. But instead it generates a random no. between 0 and total no. of rows. And, then I use that no. as offset to get a row next to that random count.

Comment: Your technique will, at best, average twice as fast as the typical `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT1`.  This is because there is no way to leap forward N rows in a table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the query you want is:

```
select x.*
from tablename x
where x.id >= random_number
order by x.id
limit 1;
```

This should use an index on `x.id` and should be quite fast.  You can combine them as:

```
select x.*
from tablename x cross join
     (select cast(max(id) * rand() as int) as random_number from tablename
     ) c
where x.id >= random_number
order by x.id
limit 1;
```

Note that you should use `max(id)` rather than `count()`, because there can be gaps in the ids.  The subquery should also make use of an index on `id`.

EDIT:

I won't be defensive about the above solution.  It returns a random id, but the id is not uniformly distributed.

My preferred method, in any case, is:

```
select x.*
from tablename x cross join
     (select count(*) as cnt from x) cnt
where rand() < 100 / cnt
order by rand()
limit 1;
```

It is highly, highly unlikely that you will get no rows with the `where` condition (it is possible, but highly unlikely).  The final `order by rand()` is only processing 100 rows, so it should go pretty fast.

Comment: This is a good answer, but it must be noted that it won't work properly if the IDs aren't sequential (e.g. you have gaps in the id field)

Comment: I accepted the answer, but maybe you should read the edit I made.

Comment: @itoctopus . . . This specfically does work when there are gaps.  Perhaps you are referring to the original question that used `count()` rather than `max()`.

Comment: Actually, count() also works pretty well with gaps, I am just getting the next row with Limit and Offset, not next PRIMARY_KEY. And, I agree that @itoctopus is mistaken.

Comment: I just found out that itoctopus is right. Your query would actually return the rows after huge gaps more frequently.

Comment: @itoctopus . . . You should be clearer on what you mean by "not work properly".

Comment: `FLUSH STATUS; SELECT ...; SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';` -- see if the numbers match the table's row count.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : My answer assumes MySql<5.5.6 where you cannot pass a variable to LIMIT and OFFSET. Otherwise, OP's method is the best.

The most reliable solution, imo, would be to rank your results to eliminate the gaps. My solution might not be optimal since I'm not used to MySQL, but the logic works (or worked in my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cea45/25)).

```
SET @total = 0;

SELECT @total := COUNT(1) FROM test;

SET @random=FLOOR(RAND()*@total)+1;
SET @rank=0;

SELECT * from 
    (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, id, name
    FROM test
    order by id) derived_table
where rank = @random;
```

I'm not sure how this structure will old if you use it on a massive query, but as long as you're within a few hundreds of rows it should be instant.

Basically, you generate a random row number with (this is one of the place where there's most probably optimization to be made) :

```
SET @total = 0;
SELECT @total := COUNT(1) FROM test;
SET @random=FLOOR(RAND()*@total)+1;
```

Then, you rank all of your rows to eliminate gaps :

```
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 as rank, id, name
FROM test
order by id
```

And, you select the randomly selected row :

```
SELECT * from 
    (ranked derived table) derived_table
where rank = @random;
```

Comment: There is no need to remove gaps or use ranks, if you just get the next row  (not next PRIMARY_KEY) to a randomly generated count or id.

Comment: There is no need to remove gaps, but selecting something random from a continuous list is much easier than an eclectic one. Basically, you have to choose between accounting for holes on every steps of your query, or patching those holes.

Comment: Actually it is based on the fact that LIMIT would automatically return the row next to the offset, doesn't matter if it's the next PRIMARY_KEY or not. And, what I wanted is a query that would work fast in all cases.

Comment: Well, if you [look around](http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/) a bit, you realize that the only other option is a order by rand(), which has terrible performance issues. I was a bit conservative in my post though, the select shouldn't be much longer than a regular one even on thousands of rows.

If you have more than a few thousands of rows, you might want to rethink your way of getting a random row (have a SP constantly extracting a few random rows and query a random row from that table for isntance).

Comment: I have already visited that page, before asking the question. And, you better read the question and my code again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92066/discussion-between-julien-blanchard-and-prakhar19).

Comment: This, too, is only an average of twice as fast as a full table scan.

Comment: I agree it's not perfect, but I fail to see a better way to query a table that has gaps.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 techniques in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/random .  None of them have to look at the entire table.

Do you have an AUTO_INCREMENT?  With or without gaps?  And other questions need answering to know which technique in that link is even applicable.

Answer (score -1):

Try caching the result of the first query and the use in the second query. Using both in the same query will be very heavy on the system.

As for the second query, try the following:

```
SELECT x FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ID = RANDOM_NUMBER
```

The above query is much faster than yours (assuming ID is indexed)

Of course, the above query assumes that you are using sequential IDs (no gaps). If there are gaps, then you will need to create another sequential field (maybe call it ID2) and then execute the above query on that field.

Comment: Of course, there are gaps, else why would have I used 2 queries. :-)